# How to start an animation loop in Tkinter for an event?

Tags: python, animation, plot, tkinter

I wrote some code using Tkinter in Python 3 that plots a graph in a canvas. I also made it such that when I move the mouse over the canvas the graph scrolls to the left.

The problem is that I want the graph to scroll when I press the space bar for example. But I don't want it to scroll 1 step each time I press the space bar but I want it to start scrolling indefinitely when I press it once and stop the scroll when I press it again. I want the space bar to be a play/pause key.

How can I accomplish this? I don't want to use matplotlib anywhere.

MY CODE AS IT IS NOW:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

# The function of the graph
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)+np.sin(3*x-1)+np.sin(0.5*(x+np.pi))+0.3*np.sin(10*x)

class GraphPlot():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # Data for the graph and steps to move to the right
        self.data_x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 1000)
        self.data_y = f(self.data_x)
        self.step = 0.1

        # A switch to delete to clear the canvas each iteration before plotting the next frame
        self.gate = False

        # Setting the Tkinter window and the canvas in place
        self.ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        ww = self.ws*0.75
        hw = self.hs*0.50
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.master, width = ww, height = hw, bg = 'black')
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.master.update()
        self.w = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.h = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas.focus_set()

        # Plot first frame
        self.drawData(self.data_x, self.data_y)

        # Plot next frames each time I press the space bar
        self.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-space>', self.updateData)

    def drawData(self, data_x, data_y):
        '''This is my function to plot a grpah in a canvas
        canvas without embedding any matplotlib figure'''

        # Setting the axis limits
        x_min, x_max = min(data_x), max(data_x)
        y_min, y_max = min(data_y), max(data_y)

        # Translating data to pixel positions inside the canvas
        pixel_x = (data_x-x_min)*self.w/(x_max-x_min)
        pixel_y = -(data_y-y_max)*self.h/(y_max-y_min)
        points = []
        for i in range(len(data_x)):
            points.append(pixel_x[i])
            points.append(pixel_y[i])
        points = tuple(points)

        # Deleting previous frame before plotting the next frame (except for the first frame)
        if self.gate:
            self.canvas.delete('curve')
        else:
            self.gate = True

        # Plotting
        self.canvas.create_line(points, fill = 'white', tag = 'curve')

    def updateData(self, event):
        # Changing data for the next frame
        self.data_x += self.step
        self.data_y = f(self.data_x)

        # Plot new frame
        self.drawData(self.data_x, self.data_y)

root = Tk()
GraphPlot(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I've tried some ideas. For example I used a new function, `PlayPause()`, with a  while loop and a new switch, `self.go`, but this didn't work as expected.

CODE THAT I EXPECTED TO WORK BUT DIDN'T:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)+np.sin(3*x-1)+np.sin(0.5*(x+np.pi))+0.3*np.sin(10*x)

class GraphPlot():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.data_x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 1000)
        self.data_y = f(self.data_x)
        self.step = 0.1
        self.go = False # The new switch
        self.gate = False
        self.ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        ww = self.ws*0.75
        hw = self.hs*0.50
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.master, width = ww, height = hw, bg = 'black')
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.master.update()
        self.w = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.h = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas.focus_set()
        self.drawData(self.data_x, self.data_y)
        self.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-space>', self.PlayPause)

    def drawData(self, data_x, data_y):
        x_min, x_max = min(data_x), max(data_x)
        y_min, y_max = min(data_y), max(data_y)
        pixel_x = (data_x-x_min)*self.w/(x_max-x_min)
        pixel_y = -(data_y-y_max)*self.h/(y_max-y_min)
        points = []
        for i in range(len(data_x)):
            points.append(pixel_x[i])
            points.append(pixel_y[i])
        points = tuple(points)
        if self.gate:
            self.canvas.delete('curve')
        else:
            self.gate = True
        self.canvas.create_line(points, fill = 'white', tag = 'curve')

    def updateData(self):
        self.data_x += self.step
        self.data_y = f(self.data_x)
        self.drawData(self.data_x, self.data_y)

    def PlayPause(self, event):
        if self.go:
            self.go = False
        else:
            self.go = True
        while self.go:
            self.updateData()

root = Tk()
GraphPlot(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method to `toggle_play_pause`, and bind the space key to it. Upon space key press, this method toggles a boolean flag `pause` that when turned off allows the `update` to be called.

`update` will keep calling itself every 10/1000 of a second, until the space key is pressed again, and the `pause` flag set to True.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)+np.sin(3*x-1)+np.sin(0.5*(x+np.pi))+0.3*np.sin(10*x)

class GraphPlot():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # Data for the graph and steps to move to the right
        self.data_x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 1000)
        self.data_y = f(self.data_x)
        self.step = 0.1

        # A switch to delete to clear the canvas each iteration before plotting the next frame
        self.gate = False

        # Setting the Tkinter window and the canvas in place
        self.ws = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.hs = master.winfo_screenheight()
        ww = self.ws * 0.75
        hw = self.hs * 0.50
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width=ww, height=hw, bg='black')
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.master.update()
        self.w = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.h = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas.focus_set()

        # Plot first frame
        self.drawData(self.data_x, self.data_y)

        # Plot next frames each time I press the space bar
        self.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-space>', self.toggle_play_pause)

        self.pause = True
        self._update_call_handle = None

    def drawData(self, data_x, data_y):
        '''This is my function to plot a grpah in a canvas
        canvas without embedding any matplotlib figure'''

        # Setting the axis limits
        x_min, x_max = min(data_x), max(data_x)
        y_min, y_max = min(data_y), max(data_y)

        # Translating data to pixel positions inside the canvas
        pixel_x = (data_x-x_min)*self.w/(x_max-x_min)
        pixel_y = -(data_y-y_max)*self.h/(y_max-y_min)
        points = []
        for i in range(len(data_x)):
            points.append(pixel_x[i])
            points.append(pixel_y[i])
        points = tuple(points)

        # Deleting previous frame before plotting the next frame (except for the first frame)
        if self.gate:
            self.canvas.delete('curve')
        else:
            self.gate = True

        # Plotting
        self.canvas.create_line(points, fill = 'white', tag = 'curve')

    def toggle_play_pause(self, dummy_event):
        self.pause = not self.pause
        if not self.pause:
            self.updateData()

    def updateData(self):
        # Changing data for the next frame
        self.data_x += self.step
        self.data_y = f(self.data_x)

        # Plot new frame
        self.drawData(self.data_x, self.data_y)
        if not self.pause:
            self._update_call_handle = root.after(10, self.updateData)
        else:
            root.after_cancel(self._update_call_handle)
            self._update_call_handle = None

root = tk.Tk()
GraphPlot(root)
root.mainloop()
```